# Reflection using generic types when class is unknown

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm loading a model with reflection:

```
private void LoadAssemblies()
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(modelDll);
    var types = assembly.GetTypes();

    inputType = assembly.GetType(types.Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("Input")).FirstOrDefault().FullName);
    outputType = assembly.GetType(types.Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("Output")).FirstOrDefault().FullName);

    inputModel = Activator.CreateInstance(inputType);
    outputModel = Activator.CreateInstance(outputType);

    inputModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonPredict);
}
```

Then I need to call a method with two generic types

```
// I can't convert this model loaded at runtime into a type to this generic method
var predEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<typeof(inputModel), typeof(outputModel)>(mlModel);
```

I've tried

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ModelOperationsCatalog)); 

/* I get an error:
System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'

instance.GetType()
        .GetMethod("CreatePredictionEngine")
        .MakeGenericMethod(inputType, outputType)
        .Invoke(this, new object[] { });
*/
```

Comment: So what are the constructors for `ModelOperationsCatalog` and why don't you just call one of them directly instead of using reflection for that part (since the type isn't a variable)?

Comment: i would like to use it directly, but i need to pass 2 generic types to this method, and these generict types depends on the model the model type, that was loaded at runtime, i cant specify a fixed one.

Comment: you can see ModelOperationCatalog here: https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/src/Microsoft.ML.Data/Model/ModelOperationsCatalog.cs

Comment: The *method* is generic but the class is not generic. You need to create an instance of the class passing an IHostingEnvironment to the constructor. But it's marked `internal` so I suspect there's another way you are meant to create instances of it, right? Looks like you need the `Model` property off a `MLContext`.

Comment: I ran out of choices.. if there is a way to use (inputType|outputType) to pass them as type to these generic parameters..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a context

```
var mlContext = new MLContext();
```

Get the model

```
var model = mlContext.Model;
```

And then call the generic method on it passing it the instance and the parameters:

```
 typeof(ModelOperationsCatalog)
            .GetMethod("CreatePredictionEngine")
            .MakeGenericMethod(inputType, outputType)
            .Invoke(instance, new object[] { param1, param2 });*/
```

Comment: Almost right.. I had to select method, because there was a method overload.

            var predEnginex = typeof(ModelOperationsCatalog).GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == "CreatePredictionEngine" && x.GetParameters().Count() == 2).FirstOrDefault()
                .MakeGenericMethod(inputType, outputType)
                .Invoke(model, new object[] { mlModel, inputSchema });